# Ribbon Auto-select Contextual Tab

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I have a ribbon in my application with a contextual tab. I have managed to get the tab to show and hide itself correctly based on what is selected in my application. My question is, how would I get it to be automatically selected (i.e. brought to front) when it is shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Just needed to do a style trigger based on the visibility:

```
 <r:RibbonTab Header="Options"  
                     ContextualTabGroupHeader="Options" 
                     Visibility="{Binding CurrentFiles.SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource DSToVisConverter}}" >
            <r:RibbonTab.Style>
                <Style TargetType="r:RibbonTab">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>                        
                </Style>                   
            </r:RibbonTab.Style>
```